# How to send asynchronous request in websocket in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
exampleSocket.send("Here's some text that the server is urgently awaiting!");
```

Is the request send to server, the browser is unresponsive until the response comes from the server. How to write asynchronous send function in websocket in JavaScript to avoid the browser unresponsive?

`var newOrderRequest = { 'MessageType': "CloseAllPositions", 'SessionToken': gSessionToken } 
var placeOrderRequestMessage = JSON.stringify(newOrderRequest); exampleSocket.send(placeOrderRequestMessage);`

Above request is sending to server, the server sending the response by taking some time ,the time between request and response  causing the browser unresponsive.

How to avoid this broser unresponsive.

Comment: No, the browser will not become unresponsive just because you call  `send`. Please show us the rest of your code, it's likely that something else is blocking.

Comment: var newOrderRequest = {
        'MessageType': "CloseAllPositions",
        'SessionToken': gSessionToken
    }
    
    var placeOrderRequestMessage = JSON.stringify(newOrderRequest);

  exampleSocket.send(placeOrderRequestMessage);